# Turn display off option does not work

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows 7 sometimes forget to turn off my display after X number minutes, even though the power settings are specifically set that way?](https://superuser.com/questions/104552/why-does-windows-7-sometimes-forget-to-turn-off-my-display-after-x-number-minute)

on my win7 (x86) laptop the "turn screen off after some idle-time" setting doesn't work anymore. The screen gets off and on immediately. Even if I turn the display "manualy" with SendMessage and SC_MONITORPOWER off it immediately gets on again.

Event log has no related entry...
I have no clue where to start looking for the problem, any suggestions how to debug the problem?

Comment: @techie007 my windows doesn't forget to turn the display off but the display gets on again immediately. It's a different question.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Have you checked/tried any of the suggestions in the other question's answers?  Perhaps try a few (ie: unplug all USB devices, check device arming, etc.), and come back and let us know what you've tried.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, my problem is diffrent from the other question. My power saving option does get activated but my screen turns on immediately.

Some facts I tried so far:
1. No USB devices are plugged in
2. No background noise mouse activity (checked with Spy++)
3. My Screensaver works
4. Disabling my only wake aware device (modem) didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Using a new and clean user account doesn't solve the problem either